# C# Process.Start Path

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

I currently have a functioning program that simply launches a separate .exe file by clicking a button. The installer I've created asks where they want to install which by default is in fodler `C:\Program Files\PRHA`.

The code that launches the programs looks like this

```
private void ivClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("C:/Program Files/PRHA/IV/IV.exe");
}
```

How can I have `Process.Start` find the path of the running application, so if the user decides to install in another directory, `Process.Start` will still work.

Comment: Are you using a deployment project in Visual Studio? Or a custom made installer?

Comment: *What I'm wondering is how to have Process.Start find the path if the user decides to install in another directory.* Remember where the program is installed, and use that path

Comment: Are both EXEs always installed alongside each other?

Comment: Currently an installer program called Install Creator, though if necessary I'll change it.

Comment: John, both EXEs are always installed alongside each other yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that you just want to get the path of the running application to launch a secondary application (in the same directory) you should be able to use:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do it this way then there is no need that both have to be in the same location.

We can try having a custom action on the installer of `IV.exe` that makes a registry entry of the installed path. And whichever is the application that needs to invoke `IV.exe` will read the registry and gets the path with that specific key.